# How to apply Karma into actual Angular2 project?

Tags: angular, karma-runner

While I am trying to integrate Karma into Angular2 project, I found the following example and understand what Karma wants to exactly accomplish. 
However, I am a little confused in how to apply this into actual project. To count the number of elements being rendered, the presented example set the number statistically. 
I do not think I can test it this way in the real application. From my understanding, I need to incoporate with response from backend. 
I tried to find some applicable examples, however, I coult not find it. If someone has experience, could you give some advices?

```
// App
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'list',
  template: '<span *ngFor="let user of users">{{ user }}</span>',
})
export class ListComponent {
  @Input() public users: Array<string> = [];
}


// App tests
import { async, inject, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

TestBed.initTestEnvironment(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting());


describe('ListComponent', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ListComponent]
    });

    this.fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ListComponent);
  });

  it('should render list', async(() => {
    const element = this.fixture.nativeElement;
    this.fixture.componentInstance.users = ['John'];
    this.fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(element.querySelectorAll('span').length).toBe(1);
  }));

});
```

Comment: You don't want to tie into your back end when unit testing. The whole point of unit testing is to put in data and make sure your component reacts properly, so if you put in one user, and your component prints one user, that's exactly what you want to achieve. Unit testing is used for testing many small sections of code, and to quickly find a problem if you make a change that breaks something. If you want to test the whole system, check out end-to-end testing using Protractor.

Comment: Ah, I remember I have read before. Thank you!